# Don't allow new lines in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

Using jQuery how can I not allow new lines to be inserted (by pressing enter or copying in text) - In semi-pseudo code...

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(){
 $(this).remove_new_lines();
});
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Would it be as crude as the following or is there a better way?

```
function removeNL(s){ 
  return s.replace(/[\n\r\t]/g,); 
}

$('textarea').keydown(function(){
 $(this).val(removeNL($(this).val));
});
```

Comment: when  user typing or when setting the content to the textarea

Comment: With all of the below solutions, I can still open up Chrome developer tools and manually edit the field contents. Or disable javascript. :)

Comment: @Rob And that's what server-side validation is for. ;)

Comment: @coreyward - Agreed, which is what I was subtly trying to point out. In most cases, though, I find that semantic form validation is completely unnecessary. It's very hard to *really* validate that submitted content is legitimate. Just validate some maxlengths and be done with it.

Comment: Yeah - obviously it is being validated server-side too, just necessary to do it front-end too for the UX.

Comment: @kieran - Right on, as long as that's in there. Too often I see someone spending a bunch of time on client side validation that's easily subverted.

Comment: @Rob Depends on your idea of valid, I suppose. The point of validating user input is usually to A) make sure the user didn't miss something (like the .com in their email address, B) that we're getting information that looks like it should (e.g. no empty comments), and C) ensuring the information we feed our models isn't going to break something (e.g. integers are integers).

Comment: @coreyward - I agree, validation of that sort is okay. It's the over-the-top stuff that gets me, like validating that a "name" field has only alpha characters (which itself is just incorrect). Once you try to start preventing users from entering semantically incorrect data (like email addresses that aren't theirs, or fake names), it's usually a lost cause (unless you want to inconvenience the users so much that it chases them off your website).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two methods to do this: check each character as it is input and return false if you don't want it to show up, or on each change/keyup you can check the entire contents. While the former is more performant, it won't work in situations where the user pastes content in that includes unwanted characters. For that reason, I recommend the latter approach, something like this (which will disallow all vertical whitespace):

With jQuery:

```
$('textarea').on('keyup', function(){
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[\r\n\v]+/g, ''));
});
```

Or using plain JavaScript (ES2015/ES6):

```
constrainInput = (event) => { 
  event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[\r\n\v]+/g, '')
}

document.querySelectorAll('textarea').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('keyup', constrainInput)
})
```

Another approach is to wait until the focus leaves the textarea, then apply the transformation. This avoids janky behavior on operating systems using synthetic, conditionally active keyboard controls. The user will see newlines until they leave the field, though, so be aware. To do this, just change the above event listener to listen for `blur` rather than `keyup`.

If you're using React, you have it made because it avoids issues with mobile browsers while letting you manage the value as it changes using controlled components:

```
class TextArea extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    value: ""
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    const value = event.target.value.replace(/[\r\n\v]+/g, "");
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  render() {
    return <textarea onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is gsub? It's saying it's not a recognized function

Comment: A Ruby method...hahaha. Whoops. Swapped in `replace()`, which is the JavaScript equivalent.

Comment: Any ideas on how to replace various new lines with just one? I tried this approach, didn't work: $('#text').val($('#text').val().replace(/\v+/g,"\n"));

Comment: maybe i didn't explain myself very good. at least 2 new lines are allowed (because of the paragraph separation). the regex i pasted above allows a maximum of one :s

Comment: Use the following instead: `.replace(/(\r\n|\n){3,}/, "\n\n")` — this matches 3 or more newlines and replaces them with two. You may be able to get away with the `\v` shortcut, but I'm not sure and don't feel like forcing Windows line-endings into a textarea to try it out. ;)

Comment: Correct code `$('textarea').keyup(function(){
  $(this).val( $(this).val().replace( /\r?\n/gi, '' ) );
});`

Comment: The `.replace(/\v+/g, '')` doesn't work. Use one posted by @XandrGuard.

Comment: This has problems on Mobile chrome. On entering the text area, the on screen keyboard just opens and closes before you can type anything.

Answer (score 8):

you can check keyCode, if it is equal to 13 simply return false

```
$('#TEXTAREA').keypress(function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == 13) return false
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(e){
 var s = $('textarea').val();
 while (s.indexOf("\n") > -1)
  s = s.replace("\n","");
 $('textarea').val(s);
});
```