# Need to only allow certain characters to be entered OR deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox. The only things I want the user to be able to enter are parentheses. They should also only be able to delete parentheses. I'm having a ton of trouble doing this though.

Right now I have a function like this:

```
        '#myTextArea input': function (el, ev) {

        }
```

I used input so it would handle people pasting.

I'm not sure how to find the character typed from this though. I especially don't know how to make sure only a parentheses was deleted. Anyone know of a good way to do this?

**Edit**
To clarify, the textbox is already populated with text. The user should just be able to add and remove parentheses to the text already there.

**Edit2**

I got it working so the user can ONLY enter parentheses. This does not take into account pasting, and does not deal with deleting. Still have no idea how to do that.....

```
        '#myTextArea keydown': function (el, ev) {
            if ((ev.keyCode != 48 && ev.keyCode != 57) || ev.shiftKey == false){
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you using backbone or any other framework?

Comment: Only things being used are JQuery and JavascriptMVC.

Comment: If they can only enter parentheses, how could they delete anything other than parentheses?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Don't allow new lines in textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959501/dont-allow-new-lines-in-textarea)

Comment: If pasting is allowed, then how do you define what was deleted?

Comment: This doesn't look as a semantically valid syntax. I'm not aware of any jQuery or javascript function that would take a selector => callback map.

Comment: @JanDvorak that's how you define handlers in JavaScriptMVC

Comment: @jbabey: I don't see how either of the solutions in the possible duplicate would work here, since the OP *does* want to allow characters in the input field that the user should not be able to type.

Comment: @WesleyMurch it's not much of a leap to change the regular expression from not accepting newlines to only accepting parens.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up selectors and event types. The syntax is `$('#mytTextArea').bind("input", function(event) {...});`.

Comment: @jbabey: Both those solutions replace the entire value of the input, what the OP wants here is to preserve the original input value and allow only adding/deleting certain characters without discarding the original characters.

Comment: So select-all-delete should delete all parantheses and keep the rest? What about select-all-paste-"12(3)"? Should that keep the non-parantheses and add "()" in the end? Many cases to account for here, you need to explain what this is for...

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is do it programatically in keyup event. I show only the case when inserting (by pressing a key or pasting).

Whether it was character key pressed or Ctrl-V, in general, there is a substring being inserted into a string. The caret position will be at the end of that substring.

My algorithm finds that substring as the string between two positions:

- end of longest common prefix (first character that is different is the start of the inserted substring)
- caret position

Then it filters the string using function filterString that will replace all non parenthesis symbols with ""

And finally updates input value to longest common prefix + filtered string + text after the caret

You need this jquery plugin for caret manipulation: http://jcaret.googlecode.com/

```
<input id="myTextArea" value="a*(b*(c+d))">
</input>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jcaret.googlecode.com/files/jquery.caret.1.02.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var old_value = $('#myTextArea').val();

function filterString(a) {
    return a.replace(/[^\(\)]/g,"");
}

$('#myTextArea').keyup(function(){
    var end_of_insertion = $(this).caret().start;
    var new_value = $(this).val();

    var i=0;

    while(i<old_value.length && i<new_value.length && old_value[i]==new_value[i]) {
        i++;
    }
    if(i>=end_of_insertion)return;

    // i now points to first different character in strings old_value and new_value

    new_value = new_value.substr(0,i)
        + filterString(new_value.substr(i,end_of_insertion-i))
        + new_value.substr(end_of_insertion);

    $('#myTextArea').val(new_value).caret({start: end_of_insertion, end: end_of_insertion});
    old_value = new_value;
});
</script>
```